# Can webpack bundle different versions of the same dependency

Tags: javascript, webpack

I've a project made of different widgets that all share the same vendor. I would like to know if I could bundle different versions of the same vendor library:

**widget A**

- lib 1.0.0

**widget B**

- lib 2.0.0

**bundle**

- widgetA.js
- widgetB.js
- vendor.js (lib 1.0.0 + lib 2.0.0)

Comment: I would also love to know this. Guess I'll need to test it. I'm trying to figure out how to configure Webpack so that multiple entry points built independently won't replace each other's versions of dependencies. I'm thinking of maintaining a separate registry module of all entry points, with entry point modules capable of providing 2 code bases from themselves: 1) full, and 2) minimal necessary for dependency resolution. Still brainstorming and learning though ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I found that NPM provides a way to alias the names of modules/libraries upon installation. I tested this and it works great, and the 2 versions of jQuery are even bundled in the same vendors.bundle by Webpack. Here's the module alias syntax:

```
npm install jquery2@npm:jquery@2
npm install jquery3@npm:jquery@3
```

Comment: Nice finding, this is quite new I can see it was released on `v6.9.0` and by the time being it's not event documented!

Comment: In can you wonder this gets the following into your package.json: `"jquery2": "npm:jquery@^2.2.4", ...`